# Example of Hilbert space with uncountable basis

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Recently, I read a functional analysis book. Seemingly, a Hilbert space can have uncountable basis. But there is not any example which has uncountable basis in this book. So, I ask here. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Check out direct integrals. You'll soon start to see why non separable Hilbert spaces are typically not studied. They're monsters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean a Hilbert basis, then you may take directly $\ell^2(X,\mu)$, where $X$ is an uncountable set and $\mu$ is the counting measure. Then, the indicator functions of the singletons are a Hilbert basis.

If you are unfamiliar with the formalism of summation over infinite sets (or equivalently, if you have a hard time figuring out how integration over the counting measure works) you can describe $\ell^2(X,\mu)$ in terms of the more mundane notion of countable series as the set of functions $f:X\to\Bbb F$ such that $f^{-1}[\Bbb F\setminus\{0\}]$ is countable and $\sum\limits_{s\in f^{-1}[\Bbb F\setminus\{0\}]}\lvert f(s)\rvert^2<\infty$, endowed with inner product $\langle f,g\rangle=\sum\limits_{s\in f^{-1}[\Bbb F\setminus\{0\}]\cap g^{-1}[\Bbb F\setminus\{0\}]}\overline{f(s)}g(s)$